# How to check if textbox empty as soon as i leave it in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, html, forms, null, textbox

I want to display "invalid name" right beside my textbox when it is empty. 
Here is my JavaScript code to check for "empty name"

```
function checkName(field) {
            var mystring = document.getElementById('na2').value;
            if (mystring===""||mystring==""||mystring==null||mystring==undefined) {
                document.getElementById('na1').innerHTML = 'Invalid!!!!!!!'
            }
        }
```

However, "invalid message" is not being displayed.

Comment: Replace `if (mystring===""||mystring==""||mystring==null||mystring==undefined)` with `if (mystring==""||mystring==null||mystring==undefined)` .Edit:Corrected after @DanielHigueras pointed out the error.

Comment: What is na1 and na2? Do you have the function assigned to an event?

Comment: @SatejS you have mystring == "" twice.

Answer (score 0):

You can use

```
function checkTextField() {
    if (document.getElementById('na2').value == '') {
        document.getElementById('na1').innerHTML = 'Invalid';
    }
}
```

or

```
function checkTextField() {
    if (!document.getElementById('na2').value) {
        document.getElementById('na1').innerHTML = 'Invalid';
    }
}
```

Working example: https://jsfiddle.net/8c6v1xk5/4/

Comment: I believe he wants to show the text in an html tag, not as an alert

Answer (score 0):

```
function checkTextField() 
{
    // if there's no value entered within the textbox
    if (!document.getElementById('na2').value) 
    {
        // Change the inner html of the error element from "" to invalid
        document.getElementById('na1').innerHTML = 'Invalid';
    }
    // otherwise there must be data present
    else
    {
        // Remove the inner html and re-set it to an empty string
        document.getElementById('na1').innerHTML = '';
    }
}
```

Comment: Your answer may be correct, however please explain how this code answers the question so that future searcher can learn the reasoning behind this.